# call static method on parameter without instantiating class in argument

Tags: java

I've really been getting into TDD and I've started using mockito in jUnit to improve my ability to test code.  I'm really loving mockito!

I've noticed that I have to change the way I think about coding, like passing collaborators as much as possible into methods and limiting work done in constructors wherever possible.

The following scenario warranted some advice from the experts here on SO.

Say I have a method, that's going to call some static methods on a certain class. E.G.

```
public void method(){
    OtherClass.staticMethod();
}
```

This is generally bad, but it's needed in my scenario.  To make the code more testable in my unit tests I'd like to avoid the dependency on OtherClass and pass it as an argument.

This doesn't work as it yields a compile time error.

```
public void method(Class<? extends OtherClass> util){
    util.staticMethod();
}
...
method(OtherClass.class);
```

This would work, but I don't like the instantiating OtherClass if I don't have to, as it's solely a class of static utility like methods:

```
public void method(OtherClass util){
     util.staticMethod();
}
...
method(new OtherClass());
```

My question to you:
Is there a better more preferable way to accomplish this without using the new keyword?

Comment: Very well formatted question for a new user, congratulations :)

Comment: I am not sure whether your last code will word if you pass an instance of a subclass of `OtherClass`. Accessing static methods via an instance seems confusing to me since it **is not related to that instance**, and it may not work the way you think it would.

Comment: BTW, use the **Singleton Pattern** instead of static methods in your case?

Answer (score 1):

> This would work, but I don't like the instantiating OtherClass if I don't have to, as it's solely a class of static utility like methods:
>
> ```
> public void method(OtherClass util){
>      util.staticMethod();
> }
> ...
> method(new OtherClass());
> ```

Actually, this doesn't work, as it will always invoke the method implementation from OtherClass, irrespective of the object you pass (even if you pass `null`).

I strongly recommend not to use reflection just to simplify testing, as this bypasses compile time checking (a wrongly spelled method name will not be detected by the compiler), and prevents the use of many features of your IDE (code completion, javadoc hovers, refactoring support, call hierarchy display, jump to definition, ...)

The common approach is to use polymorphic dispatch. In Java, this requires the method to be not static and not private. The rule of thumb therefore is: If it needs mocking, it shouldn't be static.

How to best obtain the object instance depends on your circumstances; dependency injection (your approach), the resource locator pattern, and the singleton pattern each have their own advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

In your code sample:

```
public void method(){
    OtherClass.staticMethod();
}
```

My understanding is, there should be some logic in method above apart from static method call, and that is what you want to test and not static method.

If so in such case you can write mock implementation of `OtherClass.staticMethod` which either will bypass all logic or would return desired value or implement specific logic. This will avoid dependency on `OtherClass` and gives tests explicit control on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your first approach by changing your method like this

```
public void method(Class<? extends OtherClass> clazz) throws Exception {
    Method[] mArray = clazz.getMethods();
    for(Method m :mArray) {
        if(!m.isAccessible()) m.setAccessible(true);
        if((m.getModifiers() & Modifier.STATIC) != 0) { // Here a method which is static is executed. You can change this condition, to suit your needs
            m.invoke(null);
        }
    }
}
```

And you can invoke it by calling

```
method(OtherClass.class);
```

without passing a new object of that class

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection:

```java
// exceptions management omitted
public void method(Class<? extends OtherClass> clazz, String methodName) {
    // methodName could also be a constant if it won't change
    clazz.getMethod(methodName).invoke(null);
}
```

Then,

```java
method(OtherClass.class, "staticMethod");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I just tried:

```
public void testMethod(Class<T> clazz) throws Exception{        
        Method m = clazz.getMethod("staticMethod",null);
        m.invoke(null,null);
    }
```

I assumed (as mentioned in your example) that the static method does not take any argument.

Please refer the documentations of [getMethod()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) and [inovke()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) methods.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong in a bit of static code here and there - if it doesn't access a global state:

If the static code is purely procedural

> ```
> public void method(){
>     OtherClass.staticMethod();
> }
> ```

You can mock it around method(), as long as you keep the static call as the only operation in your method

Else if your static method protects some global state, you'd be better off with a Singleton+Locator

> ```
> public class Registry {
>     DoSomethingInterface getOtherClass() {
>         return OtherClass.getSingleton();
>     }
> }
>
>
> public void method(Registry reg){
>     reg.getOtherClass().doSomething();
> }
> ```

you can then subclass the registry to provide all kind of variation to the getOtherClass() locator, so you can have a TestRegistry instantiated at test times taking care of providing a clean global state and other things

If you still need the other class to be static because you can't change it in any way (i.e. library class), you can wrap it in your interface:

> ```
> public class Registry {
>     DoSomethingInterface getOtherClass() {
>         return new DoSomethingInterface(){
>             public void doSomething() {
>                 OtherClass.staticMethod();
>             }
>         };
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps. But I had to do something similar although not for testing purposes. And this is what I came up with.

Create a class that once instantiated only has one method and it calls the other class static method. And if you want to decouple it more then create an Interface. Something like:

```
public interface MethodCaller {
    void callMethod();
}
```

And then use an instance of this as parameter for your method.

```
public void method(MethodCaller caller){
    caller.callMethod();
}
```

And to call this then do.

```
method(new MethodCaller() {
   @Override
   public void callMethod() {
       OtherClass.staticMethod();
   }
});
```

Hope this helps!